# CNAME Setup on Different Server

Tags: email-server, cname-record, mx-record

I have domain and hosting at GoDaddy.com with domain earthline.info. But my email is located at CBN.net.id. I have setup the mx with this configuration:

[image: MX Records]

But for CNAME, i'm not sure what i must setup for the mail, imap, smtp and etc.

[image: CNAME]

I'm not sure because in my outlook, incoming and outgoing server i use mail.earthline.info. Did it will make sure the mail will go through CBN.net.id server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your correct settings should be subdomains of `cbn.net.id`.

http://portal.cbn.net.id/cbprtl/cybertech/detail.aspx?x=Tips+And+Tricks&y=cybertech|5|0|9|1663

POP and IMAP currently point to the same IP address, so at the moment, if you point `mail.earthline.info` at CNAME `pop.cbn.net.id` and use `mail.earthline.info` in your mail client to connect to both POP and IMAP, it *will* work.  There's no guarantee that this will continue to work in the future.

A better idea would be to set up two subdomains:

```
pop.earthline.info. CNAME pop.cdb.net.id.
imap.earthline.info. CNAME imap.cdb.net.id.
```

And use one for POP and the other for IMAP.  That way it should continue to work in the future.

Their SMTP servers are different, so you will have to set those up individually.

```
smtp.earthline.info. CNAME smtp.cdb.net.id.
smtps.earthline.info. CNAME smtps.cdb.net.id.
```

cbn.net.id don't use the `mail` subdomain so you don't need it either.

---

One last thing: just setting your DNS records like this isn't quite enough to make everything work.  The SMTP servers at `smtp.cbn.net.id` have to be configured to accept mail for your domain and either store or forward it for you.  I assume you have done this in their admin panel or as part of your account.